# I need help changing the background image of a segmented control somehow only red works

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm new to UIKit and I'm developing a shopping cart page for a project and almost everything went great with little trouble but once I got to working with the segmented control to style it I couldn't do almost anything because it doesn't accept the changes I make.
This is the code for the segmented control:

```
import UIKit

class ShoppingCartViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl()
    let cartView = UIView()
    let wishlistView = UIView()
    
    var customTableViewController: CustomTableViewController?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
 
        
        // Create the table view controller
        customTableViewController = CustomTableViewController()
        customTableViewController?.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cartView.addSubview(customTableViewController!.view)
        
        // Set up segmented control
        segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "Cart", at: 0, animated: true)
        segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "Wishlist", at: 1, animated: true)
        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        segmentedControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        // Set up cart view
        cartView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        // Set up table view
        customTableViewController?.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cartView.addSubview(customTableViewController!.view)
        
        // Set up wishlist view
        wishlistView.isHidden = true
        
        // Add subviews
        view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
        view.addSubview(cartView)
        view.addSubview(wishlistView)
        
        // Set up constraints
        segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cartView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        wishlistView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            segmentedControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 49),
            segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            segmentedControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            segmentedControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            
            cartView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            cartView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            cartView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            cartView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            
            customTableViewController!.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cartView.topAnchor,constant: 28),
            customTableViewController!.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cartView.bottomAnchor, constant: -100),
            customTableViewController!.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cartView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            customTableViewController!.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cartView.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        
        // Add back button to navigation bar
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped))
        
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    }

        
    @objc func backButtonTapped() {
        // Pop the current view controller off the navigation stack
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

        // Get a reference to the tab bar controller
        if let tabBarController = navigationController?.tabBarController {
            // Set the home view controller as the selected view controller
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
        }
    }

        
    @objc func segmentedControlValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            cartView.isHidden = false
            wishlistView.isHidden = true
        case 1:
            cartView.isHidden = true
            wishlistView.isHidden = false
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Extraordinary is that when I try to change the backgroundColor to other backgrounds like white and stuff it doesn't work but when I change it to red it works perfectly. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please only show relevant code. Is your question only about the segment control's `backgroundColor`? What happens exactly when you set it to anything other than `.red`? Why does your title mention background image but your question and code only talk about background color? Which is it?

Comment: I just posted the question saying that other colors like white and light colors don't work only strong colors work

Comment: "Don't work" doesn't tell us anything. That could means many possible issues. That's why I asked what actually happens exactly. Do you get unexpected colors? Does the control not change at all? Compiler errors? Runtime errors? Do you see any difference between running with the device/simulator in light mode versus dark mode?

Comment: ok about errors there's none it just doesn't change anything at all stays the same with or without that line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you check how UISegmentedControl as shown in the images bellow you will find that there are UIImageViews above the background which will give a blur effect[image: Image1]

[image: image2]

And to overcome that situation you have to options
**First you do as follow**

```
    segmentedControl.backgroundColor = .red // of course you can replace this with white and it will work 
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentTintColor = .green // this color for the selected segment 
    
    segmentedControl.subviews[0].alpha = 0
    segmentedControl.subviews[1].alpha = 0
```

**but this is not recommended at all**

**Second solution**
is to replace  UIImageViews' images using this function [setBackgroundImage(_:for:barMetrics:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618571-setbackgroundimage) first you add images in your asset catalog with the color you prefer for example i added white for unselected segment and a green for selected segment

```
    segmentedControl.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "white"), for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    segmentedControl.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "green"), for: .selected, barMetrics: .default)
    segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.black], for: .normal)
```

[image: image4]